# What is the status of support for touch events on non-mobile browsers?

Tags: html, touch, cross-browser

Multi-touch isn't just for mobile devices any more. When will I be able to start using touch and gesture events in web apps on my MacBook Pro (or any other device with a touchpad or trackpad)? For example, I'd like to pinch-to-zoom on Google Maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with other HTML5 features, caniuse.com keeps a pretty good pulse on things:

http://caniuse.com/touch

(currently it's not looking good)